# How do I save a picture embedded in an Excel document without losing quality?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pictures

When I right click on the image, there is no option to save picture as...

I usually copy and paste the picture into MS Paint and save from there, but at a loss of quality.

Comment: In what way do you loose quality? When I try, and save as `.png` or `.bmp` I get a reasonable result. I mean, I don't see any loss of quality.

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility is to change the extension of the file from `.DOCX` to `.ZIP`, then unzip the file, you should see a directory called `word` in which there is a subdirectory called `media` which contains all the embedded images.

NB: Do this on a copy of the file

Comment: For Excel, you would do this with an `.xlsx` file and find the media folder in the `xl` directory.

Answer (score 3):

Try copying and pasting it into Microsoft Word then right click on the picture and click Save As in the context menu.

Comment: When I try what you suggest in my `Office 2007` package, there is no `Save as ...` option in the context menu of the image in Word. Is it perhaps version dependent?

Answer (score 3):

One hack-ish solution is to save a copy of the workbook as a website. This will create a folder of website files. Inside the folder, you will find a copy of the image file.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the picture into MS PowerPoint than when you right click on the image, there is  option to save picture. Save from there you wont lose quality.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that sometimes if you force to change the extension to .zip, and unzipping will pop an error.
for saving as web method, the image quality is still lossy

what I found the best way is to open them in Apple iWork, then click the image, then on the right side, there's an image tab, in this section, under image info, there's an image icon (kinda like a preview file place holder icon), drag that icon to whatever folder you want to save, and boom! original quality image.
The downside of this method is that you have to do them one by one.

Comment: Another downside is that I believe the OP was using WIndows, your solution would only work on Macs.

Answer (score 0):

Best Possible way to do it retaining original Picture quality is to select one picture. Next press Ctrl+A to select all pictures. Once all picture are selected right click and select "Size and Properties..". A new windows will be open in right sidebar. From there you can easily increase the size of all pictures in same Excel File to your required size. Once done. Save the excel file as .html webpage extension. A folder will be created with same file name. Inside folder you will get all your pictures with good quality and size.

Sorry for my poor English. God bless you all.

Answer (score 0):

Save as your excel file as a Web Page with the extension *.htm or *.html and find all the images of the excel sheet in a folder with the same name of the file.