# Round-tripping a image through Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, image-conversion

I tried dragging a .tif image into word, and then saving that image from within word as a .tif image file. The resulting output file had more bytes (122 kB vs 72 kB) but fewer pixels (624 pixels square vs. 672 pixels square). Is there a way to bring an image into a Word document, and then export it, so that the image is preserved perfectly?

As a notary, I wish to assure that my seal in a notarized document is exactly what I want it to be. Also, if anyone ever asserts I sealed a document, I want to be able to detect if the image in the document is different than the one I have saved on my computer (as one of several methods of verifying a document).

Comment: Inserting an image is not a method of "securing" a document in any verifiable way. You should be using the "document signing" facility which will attach a digital signature that verifies the contents of the document at the point where it was signed. If the document changes then the signature is immediately invalidated. Inserting a picture is meaningless to validate how and when a document might have been modified. People could simply edit a document after you insert the image and it would still be "valid".

Comment: Mokubai, I am aware of the need for PKI digital signatures. But some US states also impose a requirement to provide a seal. A full understanding of the image import/export issue will allow me to explain the issues better.

Comment: [This may help](https://superuser.com/questions/1325088/how-do-i-save-a-picture-embedded-in-an-excel-document-without-losing-quality/1325342#1325342) but I fully agree with @Mokubai. The presence or absence of an image won't affect the digital signature, just rely on the signature to see if a document was modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [method explained by](https://superuser.com/questions/1325088/how-do-i-save-a-picture-embedded-in-an-excel-document-without-losing-quality/1325342#1325342) cybernetic.nomad works. Make a copy of the Word file, change the copy's extention from .docx to .zip, unzip. Within the unzipped folder, find the word folder, and within that find the media folder. The image found this way seems identical to the original.

The reason I had trouble with this with my first attempt was the version of the seal I tested was too large to fit within the margins of a 8.5 inch by 11 inch page, so Word altered the image to fit. When I increased the page size in the layout tab, and did the test over, it worked.